# Database backup of azure database deployed in local sql server management studio

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, azure, backup

Can anyone help me in doing this task? I am using my sql azure database in my local machine's sql server management studio 2008 r2. What my issue is, I am trying to take backup of a database from my c# console application using the following methods:

- **using smo**: showing error at "sqlBackup(server)" method.
  The error details like -

  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlPropertyMetadataProvider.PropertyNam
  eToIDLookupWithException(String propertyName, PropertyAccessPurpose pap)
     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetDbComparer(Boolean inSe
  rver)
     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.InitializeStringComparer()

  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.AbstractCollectionBase.get_StringCompar
  er()
     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SimpleObjectCollectionBase.InitInnerCol
  lection()
     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.InitializeChildCollec
  tion(Boolean refresh)
     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.GetEnumerator()
- **using "backup database" command**, this showing command not supported in this version of sql server. After searching in internet, i found that this command wont support for azure databases in ssms.
  Can anyone please provide me solution to solve this.

Answer (score 10):

You can not backup the Database in Azure Sql Service. When try to Backup Shows this Error

> Statement 'BACKUP DATABASE' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

So Backup Azure SQL Service by 
Right Click on Db --> Tasks --> Export data Tier Application --> Set Location
Creates a bacpac file after export,   then it can be import via [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh710052.aspx)

Note: Be aware there are export and extract. The extract option only copies the schema, so if you need the data as wel make sure to use the export variant.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, SQL server instance doesn't allow database migrations between two different target servers such as local and azure or vice versa.

The below tool can help run the scripts on one server to another. Keep in mind that when you run them it restores the schema and the data fully. You can alter the settings in Advanced option.

> https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/